# Domain redirect according geographic location

Tags: azure, cakephp-3.0, azure-web-app-service

What i want to do is:

- have two domains been served by the same code (pointing to the same folder)
- each one using its own database and theme (css, images)
- separate clients been registered in US to interact with databases based in US from those been registered in EU to interact with databases based in EU. Even if they try to login from an other region.

I don't know if that is possible with Azure, what structure i need, or what tools to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azure Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview) works at the DNS level and enables us to control the distribution of traffic across our application endpoints according to one of several traffic-routing methods, you could try to use it. [This blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CloudPowerHowToScaleAzureWebsitesGloballyWithTrafficManager.aspx) explained how to use scale Azure Websites globally with Traffic Manager, please refer to it.